# Can't obtain the location from Wi-Fi network data in my UWP APP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm writing an UWP APP.

Recently, I found the Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync API always obtain the position from IP address even my device connected WIFI.

But before, while my device obtain the position and the position source always return WIFI.

If the position is from IP address, it return the wrong location. Cause I'm using a VPN to connect network, it always display the VPN server's location.

If the position is from Wi-Fi, then the location is correct.

I also tried the Maps APP it also display the wrong location currently.

So I think my device should changed somethings, like block the device obtain the position from Wi-Fi network data. I tried to find the root cause, but I still don't know how to make the device can obtain the position from WIFI.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's not a development issue. It should be related to the order of the network port and had nothing to do with the `Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync API`.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be a system level issue. I tried the same APP on another device and it works well.

Comment: Disable the local network and this could confirm if the reason is the network port.

Comment: I didn't get you. Actually the GetGeopositionAsync API communicates over the Internet with a Microsoft-hosted web service to look up location-related information from a database. So if disable the network, it will return timeout exception.

Comment: Make sure you only connect to the Wifi.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: So the issue should be related to VPN, the network port is the cause.

Comment: No, another device also use the same VPN and the position source is Wi-Fi and the location is correct.

Comment: OK, that is beyond my knowledge. It's not a coding question.

Comment: Yes, thanks for you reply.